# Text - one label for every single word

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My goal is to display text with feature, that you can tap on any word of displayed text and it will do something with this selected word.

I choose the label approach. It means that every word in text will be in it's own label. And then I can rise tapped event on that label.

But I can't find out how to format that "group" of labels into "nice" formated text.

My idea was:

```
private void ReadPageViewModel_ReloadPageEvent(string text)
    {

        MyLayout.Spacing = 2; //MyLayout is StackLayout
        MyLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;

        //MyLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;

        var splitedtText = text.Split(';');
        foreach(var item in splitedtText)
        {
            MyLayout.Children.Add(new Label {Text = item , HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand });
        }
    }
```

Every try results in wrong formated text.

Could you give me some advice? Am I using wrong layout? Or is there some easy trick that I don't know?

EDIT:

Screenshots:

This is just text inserted into label, this is what I want to achieve with 1 label for every word in this text.

[image: goal]

One of many tries (result of sample above)

[image: bad formatting]

Comment: What would be your input and desired output?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you have and what you want?

Comment: Input would be just text. For example 5 sentences and output would be text composed of labels ( 1 label for 1 word), normally formatted, like If I had one label with text.

Comment: Yes, I will upload some screenshots.

Comment: I would use one label and calculate which word did user click.

Comment: Is there an option to know on which position/index I tapped, or do you suggest to calculate it from some absolute coordination ?

Comment: @HonzaBejvl I think you need to set TextAlignment for label and may i know why MyLayout horizontal options to end? Please upload screenshot for better understand.

Comment: @Mounika MyLayout horizontal options to end is nonsense, it was just copypaste fail. I uploaded screenshots.

Comment: Can you also provide the text in comment pls?(to copy paste for testing)

Comment: Chose a readonly TextBox and use  textBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location); in the MouseClick..

Comment: @Mr.Koçak input string text that I used in samples: ahoj;jak;se;mas;pisu;slova;aby;davala;smysl;a;tak;se;pokousim;napsat;celou;knizku;ktereou;si;potom;prehraju;a;zobrazim;krase;podle;lableu;do;radek;ahoj;jak;se;mas;pisu;slova;aby;davala;smysl;a;tak;se;pokousim;napsat;celou;knizku;ktereou;si;potom;prehraju;a;zobrazim;krase;podle;lableu;do;radek;ahoj;jak;se;mas;pisu;slova;aby;davala;smysl;a;tak;se;pokousim;napsat;celou;knizku;ktereou;si;potom;prehraju;a;zobrazim;krase;podle;lableu;do;radek;ahoj;jak;se;mas;pisu;slova;aby;davala;smysl;a;tak;se;pokousim;napsat;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your time. I found answer. Something like wrappanel was what I was looking for. But xamarin.forms doesn't have one so I had to help myself.

I found this wrappanel classes
https://gist.github.com/NicoVermeir/7ffb34ebd639ed958382 and 
https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Evolve13/Evolve13/Controls/WrapLayout.cs

Pick one wrappanel class and include it in project. Then add namespace to your view and it is all.

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SecretProject75.Controls;assembly=SecretProject75"
<controls:AwesomeWrappanel Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyWarappicek" Orientation="Horizontal"></controls:AwesomeWrappanel>
```